# How to make the git branch name part of the SonarQube project name?

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins, tfs, sonarqube

I'm using TFS as my scm, Jenkins, and SonarQube.
I'm trying to run a build for my maven project, and I'd like to trigger SonarQube as well.
I have everything working fine, but I'd like to add the name of the branch from TFS as part of the project key in SonarQube.

So, in my `pom.xml` file, I have the following line in my properties.

```
<sonar.projectKey>com:${env.GIT_BRANCH}</sonar.projectKey>
```

I then get this error:

> "com.origin/master" is not a valid project or module key. Allowed
>   characters are alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with at least one
>   non-digit.

I was wondering if there's a way for me to parse this variable to get rid of the "origin/" so that I can make this a valid project key.

I can do `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey="com:%GIT_BRANCH:~7%"` but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this having everything in the `pom.xml` file

EDIT: I'm building with Jenkins

Comment: How do you run the build? with TFS or Jenkins? If you build with TFS, you can use variable BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME instead of GIT_BRANCH, it will retrieve the last path segment in the ref. See [build variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables), In TFS you can use task "Jenkins Queue Job", it can transfer the parameters with [Job parameters](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/jenkins-queue-job#arguments) setting.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I'm building with Jenkins :/ Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sonar.branch` property.

See [SonarQube Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).